# Get the boolean from Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#, fluent

I want to get the boolean value from the following fluent function:

```
public IGridWithOptions<T> CursorPointerWhen(Func<T, bool> propertySpecifier)
{
   bool r = ????

   return this;
}
```

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to *have* a `T` value in order to call the delegate:

```
public IGridWithOptions<T> CursorPointerWhen(Func<T, bool> propertySpecifier)
{
    T input = GetInputFromSomewhere();
    bool r = propertySpecifier(input);    
    // ...
    return this;
}
```

It's impossible to do this without a `T`. For example, consider this:

```
Func<string, bool> longString = x => x.Length > 100;
```

What is the "value" of that? It only makes any sense in the context of a particular string. We don't have much information about what you're trying to do here, but you'll need to get an instance of `T` from somewhere - or change your method argument.

Comment: aren't you wanting the `<T>` after the method name there

Comment: @Jonesy: There isn't one in the question... it could easily be a method in a generic type.

Comment: Thx Jon, you are right. This location was not the right place to have the T instance. This is a Grid component and I checked the source of it to see how other properties where set this way, and I changed the code towards it. Now I have the T instance and I can invoke it :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can call like a `method` in your class, since you have the first `T` argument, for sample:

```
T argument = /* get a instance of generic T argument */;
bool r = propertySpecifier(argument);
```